# Cloud composer Airlfow DAG latency issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

We had a DAG which has 6 steps, we observed if step1 is completed by 10:39PM, step2 starts @11:20PM. How to troubleshoot this latency issue. We are not seeing any logs in DAG steps and Cloud Logging.

Comment: Is not clear why do you consider this as a latency issue, please share more details about your use case and why do you think this is a latency issue

Comment: I have 3 tasks in my DAG, i want all tasks to be completed by 3min. But due to lag it is taking more than 30mins..Issue is not with task run but the delay to run the task.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no much information to be able to determine what could be causing a latency, what I would recommend to try to alleviate the issue is the following:

1. Check the logs within the time frame of the latency to see if additional errors could be causing this (e.g. errors while trying to reach a GCS bucket), if so try to fix them
2. Increase the value for `max_threads`, the scheduler will spawn multiple threads in parallel to schedule dags (e.g numbers of cpus where scheduler runs - 1).
3. Increase the value for `scheduler_heartbeat_sec`, which controls how frequent the airflow scheduler gets the heartbeat and updates the job’s entry in database.

NOTE: Recommendations 2 and 3 are mentioned in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#how-to-reduce-airflow-dag-scheduling-latency-in-production) about how to reduce airflow dag scheduling latency in production.

4. [Here](http://max_active_runs_per_dag) is another set of recommendations within the Airflow documentation on how DAGs can be run faster, set the `max_active_runs` to a higher value is also a recommendation.
5. Restart the scheduler to discard any issues with it, how to perform this is well explained by a colleague in the following Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859609/cloud-composer-airflow-jobs-stuck)

Comment: Thank you for your response. How to check max_threads and scheduler_heartbeat_sec in schedular pod?

Comment: This are parameters you set on the [config file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0d499db9b7641f7a7419db63e7c2fe64c5229508/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L529), if you are referring to how to verify if this values are applied, you should be seen an increase of use in vCPUs in you environment, this depends on how many DAGs are running on parallel

Comment: How to reduce airflow dag scheduling latency in production?
parsing_processes: Scheduler will spawn multiple threads in parallel to parse dags. This is controlled by parsing_processes with default value of 2. User should increase this value to a larger value (e.g numbers of cpus where scheduler runs + 1) in production.

If you're using Airflow 1.10.x, consider moving to Airflow 2, which has reduced dag scheduling latency dramatically, and allows for running multiple schedulers

Where to find this parsing-processes value, It is not there in airflow.cfg